# ADF - Lookup Activity Max Value

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to set up a metadata parquet file on storage account which would contain watermark.There would be three columns in it. Now I want to use lookup activity to get the latest value from a column and pass it to copy activity and then append new latest value to the file. Is this possible in ADF with lookup?

I was able to set up lookup activity and read the files but do not know how to get max value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give a sample date as starting value to the  `update max timestamp`  variable. We will compare the current last modified date in a loop to this variable and if its greater, then update this variable with current modified date.

So, give sample date, here I am giving last year date  `@subtractFromTime(utcnow(),1,'year')`.

[image]

Then get lookup to get the file content and give your lookup activity output array  `@activity('LookUp1').output.value`  to For Each and make sure to check the  **Sequential**. Here I have given my array parameter.

[image]

Inside ForEach, take an if activty and use below expression to compare the dates.

```json
@greaterOrEquals(ticks(item().timestamp), ticks(variables('update max timestamp')))
```

[image]

Inside  **True activities**, use set variable activities to update the  `update max timestamp` to max timestamp.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried replicating but got stuck a bit. So when creating lookup activity I connect to the desired file and read the content? I do not know where to put this output and also I see recursively only as option. Also this file will be ever growing. Iterating over it will not be a problem later on?

Comment: yes, while creating lookup activity you- need to connect the desired file and read the content. no need to select the recursively. put the output of lookup in For each activity as I demonstrated.